# Dynamic Grouping in SSRS 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am developing a report that have parameter like

RowGroupLevel1,
RowGroupLevel2,
ColumnGroupLevel1,
ColumnGroupLevel2,
ColumnGroupLevel3

Row Group Contain Category, Executive Name, Client Name Like Field
Column Group Contain Year,Quarter,Month Field.

So My requirement is as like except Level1 in Row and Column Grouping other fields are optional. 

For An Example : if I am selecting as below 

scenario 1 :
RowGroupLevel1 - Category
RowGroupLevel2 - Executive Name
ColumnGroupLevel1 - Year
ColumnGroupLevel2 - Quaker
ColumnGroupLevel3 - Month

scenario 2 :
RowGroupLevel1 - Category
RowGroupLevel2 - 
ColumnGroupLevel1 - Year
ColumnGroupLevel2 - Month
ColumnGroupLevel3 -

so as per above scenario  how I can grouping my report dynamically.

Please help me to create any type of SSRS report.

Thanks in advance.
Ankit Gusani

Comment: You can have group expressions read parameter values: `=Fields(Parameters!FirstFieldName.Value).Value`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to first of all write your query which pulls forward the results like this.

### SQL Server Query

```
SELECT  DATEPART(WEEK,  Date_Column) AS [Weekly]
       ,DATEPART(MONTH, Date_Column) AS [Monthly]
       ,DATEPART(YEAR, Date_Column)  AS [Yearly]
       ,SUM(Some_Column)             AS Total
FROM Table_Name
GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH, Date_Column) 
        ,DATEPART(WEEK,  Date_Column)
        ,DATEPART(YEAR, Date_Column)
```

### SSRS Report

Add a Matrix Data region. Drag and drop `Total` column to `DATA`.

Create a Parameter say `GROUP ON` of `Text` type, and provide values

```
1) Weekly
2) Monthly
3) Yearly
```

Now below in `ROW GROUPS` pane, right click the only visible Row Group and goto `GROUP PROPERTIES`
In `GROUP ON` section put following expression.

```
=SWITCH(
         Parameters!Groupby.Value = "Weekly",  Fields!Weekly.Value
        ,Parameters!Groupby.Value = "Monthly", Fields!Monthly.Value
        ,Parameters!Groupby.Value = "Yearly",  Fields!Yearly.Value
        )
```

Use the exactly same Expression on Data region `ROWS` section.

For Column name you can use the following Expression...

```
=SWITCH(
         Parameters!Groupby.Value = "Weekly",  "Weekly"
        ,Parameters!Groupby.Value = "Monthly", "Monthly"
        ,Parameters!Groupby.Value = "Yearly",  "Yearly"
        )
```

and you are good to go.

**Important Note**

SSRS is a cool tool for data presentation, not so cool when it comes to Data manipulation, to get better performance do all sorts of Data Manipulation closer to source (database, SQL Server).

All of the presentation stuff should be handled on SSRS.